# Can I use a GTK# component inside a WinForms form?

Tags: .net, winforms, mono, gtk#

Can I use a Mono GTK# component inside a WinForms form?

Especially, I want to use the [Mono.Texteditor](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/source/trunk/monodevelop/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.  They have different event loops that are going to compete for events.  It is technically possible, but it's likely going to be way more work than you are interested in doing.